# Array allocation in structure

Tags: c

I have the following code and I need to allocate memory for `char data[]`.

Can't change the struct, though:

```
struct ppm {
    unsigned xsize;
    unsigned ysize;
    char data[]; 
};

struct ppm *img = malloc(sizeof(struct ppm));
if (!img) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Chyba alokace pameti.\n");
     exit(1);
}
if (fscanf(fp, "%x %x", &img->xsize, &img->ysize) != 2) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Spatna velikost obrazku '%s'\n", filename);
     exit(1);
}
if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->xsize, img->ysize, fp)) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Nepodarilo se nacist pixely z '%s'\n", filename);
     exit(1);
}
```

Can someone help me out ?

I would like to have data allocated like this:

```
img->data = malloc(sizeof(char)*(img->xsize * img->ysize * 3));
```

Comment: "Many things" "it doesn't work" Could you please be less vague? You should provide good, wholesome details regarding your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, it went for fprintf, then exit

Comment: OT:  regarding: `sizeof(char)`  This expression is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression from the parameters to `malloc()`

Comment: OT:  regarding this kind of statement: `fprintf(stderr, "Chyba alokace pameti.\n");`  When an error indication comes from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred. Suggest using: `perror( "Chyba alokace pameti." );  As that will output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you to debug it

Comment: regarding: `fread(img->data, 3 * img->xsize, img->ysize, fp))`  have you looked at the actual image file to verify that each pixel is 3 characters?  Images can have anywthere from 1 to 4 characters per pixel

Comment: regarding: `if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->xsize, img->ysize, fp)) 
     fprintf(stderr, "Nepodarilo se nacist pixely z '%s'\n", filename);
     exit(1);`  and `char data[];`   1) need to `malloc()` enough memory to hold the whole pixel array (and remember that each row in that array has to be a multiple of 2 regardless of the actual row length.)  2) so this: `char data[];`  Should be: `char *data;`

Comment: regarding: `if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->xsize, img->ysize, fp)) `  need to check the returned value to assure it is img->xsize`  And again, the xsize needs to be rounded up to a multiple of 2 before trying to read the data

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for your help, but i canť change char data[], because of my teacher, but i will try to fix other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct ppm {
    unsigned xsize;
    unsigned ysize;
    char data[]; 
};

struct ppm *img = malloc(sizeof(struct ppm));
```

You have no space to put something in *data*, so `fread(img->data, 3 * img->xsize, img->ysize, fp)` will write out of the allocated block

Use *realloc* to increase the size of *img* when you have the sizes, do

```
img = realloc(img, sizeof(ppm) + 3 * img->xsize * img->ysize);
```

before

```
if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->xsize, img->ysize, fp))
```

Warning :

- you do *fread* just after *fscanf* that means the beginning of the data is just after the end of the second number, if you have for instance a newline after the second number ,that newline is part of the data read by *fread*
- if the result of *fread* is not 0 you consider it is an error, probably you wanted to do `if (fread(...) != 3 * img->xsize * img->ysize)`. Note to check the result of *fread* is not 0 is not enough  to be sure you read all because may be you did not read all even this is not an error

Comment: But how i realloc the structure only for data[] ?

Comment: @Zakys98 the effect is like to increase only the _data_, except that the address can change but even in that case the previous contents is copied in the new

Comment: i made this x=img->xsize;
    y=img->ysize; img = realloc(img, sizeof(char)*(x * y * 3)); But stilly fails on fread

Comment: @Zakys98 funny, I edited my answer at the same time, you consider there is an error when _fread_ do not return 0, you want the reverse or better compare with `3 * img->xsize * img->ysize
`

Comment: @Zakys98 read again what I said, to do `if(fread(...))` or `if(fread()...)!=0)` is exactly the same thing, you wanted `if(fread(...) == 0)` but as I said this is not the right test to do